# How to use SQL - INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a script which captures tweets and puts them into a database.  I will be running the script on a cronjob and then displaying the tweets on my site from the database to prevent hitting the limit on the twitter API.

So I don't want to have duplicate tweets in my database, I understand I can use 'INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' to achieve this, but I don't quite understand how to use it.

My database structure is as follows.

Table - Hash
  id (auto_increment)
  tweet
  user
  user_url

And currently my SQL to insert is as follows:

```
$tweet = $clean_content[0];
$user_url = $clean_uri[0];
$user = $clean_name[0];

$query='INSERT INTO hash (tweet, user, user_url) VALUES ("'.$tweet.'", "'.$user.'", "'.$user_url.'")';
mysql_query($query);
```

How would I correctly use 'INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' to insert only if it doesn't exist, and update if it does?

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You need a "unique field" in list of fields to insert. If `tweet`, `user` and `user_url` are regular fields (i.e., they are not `unique`), it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need some UNIQUE KEY on your table, if user_url is tweer_url, then this should fit (every tweet has a unique url, id would be better).

```
CREATE TABLE `hash` (
  `user_url` ...,
  ...,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_url` (`user_url`)
);
```

and its better to use INSERT IGNORE on your case

```
$query='INSERT IGNORE INTO hash (tweet, user, user_url) VALUES ("'.$tweet.'", "'.$user.'", "'.$user_url.'")';
```

ON DUPLICATE KEY is useful when you need update existing row but you want to insert just once

Comment: Thanks for your response, this seems like it would work for me. Although I think I will use the ID of the twitter post rather than the URL, I assume the ID is the 11 digit number, for example - 12935503743

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$query='INSERT INTO hash (tweet, user, user_url) 
        VALUES ("'.$tweet.'", "'.$user.'", "'.$user_url.'") 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tweet = VALUES(tweet)';
```

Answer (score 0):

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doesn't seem to be the right solution here, as you don't want to update if the value is already in the table.

I would use Twitter's own unique Status ID field (which should be unique for each tweet) instead of your hash id. Add that as a field on your table, and define it as the primary key (or as a unique index.) Then use REPLACE INTO, including the status ID from Twitter.

This has the advantage that you can always track your record back to a unique Tweet on twitter, so you could easily get more information about the Tweet later if you need to.