# create a mysql record if it doesnt exist, else update it

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to modify this MySQL query to insert the row only if it does not exist. Otherwise, I would like to update the existing row.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE hqfjt_email_history SET datesent = ['datesent'],emailformname = ['emailformname'],leadname = ['leadname']
WHERE emailformname = ['emailformname'] AND leadname = ['leadname']") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
EDIT >>

Would this be correct ?

```
INSERT INTO hqfjt_email_history datesent = ['datesent'],emailformname =     ['emailformname'],leadname = ['leadname'] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hqfjt_email_history SET     datesent = ['datesent'],emailformname = ['emailformname'],leadname = ['leadname']
WHERE emailformname = ['emailformname'] AND leadname = ['leadname']
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have tried the above and get the error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'datesent = ['datesent'],emailformname = ['emailformname'],leadname = ['leadname'' at line 1

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE !
Ok, I  tried this and it creates the record ok :

If I do this though, nothing happens, nothing gets updated or created ???? :

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO hqfjt_email_history (id, leadname, emailformname, datesent)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]','$_POST[leadname]','$_POST[emailformname]','$_POST[datesent]') ON         DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hqfjt_email_history (datesent) VALUES ('$_POST[datesent]')     WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'");
?>
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720295/how-to-use-sql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

You will need to have a key defined on the table of types `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Which will update the existing row or will create a new one if it doesn't exist, also the syntax is similar to `INSERT`.

It does exactly what `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does, but I think this approach is more elegant.

Comment: <?php
$query = mysql_query("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM hqfjt_email_history WHERE emailformname='$_POST[emailformname]' AND leadname='$_POST[leadname]')
REPLACE INTO hqfjt_email_history (datesent) VALUES ('$_POST[datesent]') WHERE emailformname='$_POST[emailformname]' AND leadname='$_POST[leadname]'
ELSE
REPLACE INTO hqfjt_email_history (id, leadname, emailformname, datesent) VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[leadname]','$_POST[emailformname]','$_POST[datesent]')
");
?>

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

for that. Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO <table> (<field1>, <field2>) VALUES (<value1>, <value2>)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE <field2> = 'update CONTENT';
```

important is the primary key (underlined in phpMyAdmin table).

Comment: Keyname Type Unique Packed Field Cardinality Collation Null Comment

Comment: http://drupal.org/files/issues/phpmyadmin_primary_key.png - look here is the primary key the "class_schedule_id"

Answer (score 0):

read  this url

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

check the database emailformname and leadname are unique