# PHP / MySQL : Insert if doesnt exist else update

Tags: php, mysql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create a mysql record if it doesnt exist, else update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666569/create-a-mysql-record-if-it-doesnt-exist-else-update-it)

I have created a bit of PHP that gets data from a CSV and updates a Database Table to match the CSV's data.

My next task is, To check if the record exists, based on the unique column (sku). If it does exist update the database table dependant on the change. 
Otherwise if that SKU column doesnt match do the INSERT.

The code I've got at the moment runs, However the issue I have is that if a new item is created it seems to run the update through the already existing records.

My code can be found on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8XGf2499)

Or also here...

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if(!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db_lemonstand", $con);

class csvIterator extends LimitIterator
{
public function __construct($path)
{
    $csv = new SplFileObject($path);
    $csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    parent::__construct($csv, 1);
}
}
 foreach (new csvIterator('data/catalogue.csv') as $entry) {

$name = $entry[23];

/* Replace Strings To Make URL Name */
$search_array = array(" ", "/", "+");
$replace_array = array("-");
$url_name = strtolower($name);
$url_name = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $url_name);

$long_desc = $entry[9];
$short_desc = $entry[23];
$manufacturer = $entry[11];
$price = $entry[15];
$sku = $entry[2];
$weight = $entry[29];
$width = $entry[30];
$height = $entry[5];
$enabled = '1';
$created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$product_type_id = '1';
$tax_class_id = '1';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($entry);
echo '</pre>';

// Check see if products' SLU already exists or not
$product_exists = "SELECT sku FROM shop_products WHERE sku = '$sku'";
$result = mysql_query($product_exists, $con);

$exists = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($exists == 0 )
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO shop_products (name, description, short_description, url_name, price, sku, weight, width, height, enabled, created_at, tax_class_id, product_type_id) VALUES ('$name', '$long_desc', '$short_desc', '$url_name', '$price', '$sku', '$weight', '$width', '$height', '$enabled', '$created_at', '$tax_class_id', '$product_type_id')";
    $insert_data = mysql_query($insert, $con);
}
else
{
    $update = "UPDATE shop_products SET name = '$name', description = '$long_desc', short_description = '$short_desc', url_name = '$url_name', price = '$price', sku = '$sku', weight = '$weight', height = '$height', enabled = '$enabled', created_at = '$created_at', tax_class_id = '$tax_class_id', product_type_id = '$product_type_id'";
    $update_data = mysql_query($update, $con);

    if (!mysql_query($update,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How can this code run properly? Your update statement has no where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
INSERT INTO mytable on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

Comment: Hi @Sashi Kant it is going to be a product feed, Where that data is going to be consistently different. Their would be too many checks on duplicate

Comment: @StuBlackett You already check for updates with your select. With this you save the additional query.

Comment: Thanks @OlafDietsche I will run through that. As you already stated the WHERE clause is quite pivotal too, School boy error in that I forgot to add that :(

Answer (score 2):

You must set unique key for your table (one or more fields) and than you can use this ability.
In my example I have unique key (template, date)

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO myTable
        (`template`,`date`,`count`) VALUES
        ("' . $template . '","' . $curDate . '", 1)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1';
```

Answer (score 2):

Store store you fields in a var as $fields or anything else that you want and execute this query for that you need a single field as reference that's why i included $Id

**INSERT INTO table_name SET id = '$Id', $fields ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $fields**